# Extracting variable number of fields using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am new to this website and came here because I am really struggling with a problem of extracting information from a JSON file. The tricky part is that there are variable number of fields, so I can't get away with simple syntax.

Here's a sample code:

```
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "1",
    "address_name": {
      "address_spec": {
        "@addr_no": "1",
        "full_address": "Tel Aviv Univ, Eitan Berglas Sch Econ, IL-69978 Tel Aviv, Israel",
        "organizations": {
          "@count": "2",
          "organization": [
            "Tel Aviv Univ",
            {
              "@pref": "Y",
              "#text": "Tel Aviv University"
            }
          ]
        },
        "suborganizations": {
          "@count": "1",
          "suborganization": "Eitan Berglas Sch Econ"
        },
        "city": "Tel Aviv",
        "country": "Israel",
        "zip": {
          "@location": "BC",
          "#text": "IL-69978"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "1",
    "address_name": {
      "address_spec": {
        "@addr_no": "1",
        "full_address": "MIT, Cambridge, MA 02139 USA",
        "organizations": {
          "@count": "2",
          "organization": [
            "MIT",
            {
              "@pref": "Y",
              "#text": "Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)"
            }
          ]
        },
        "city": "Cambridge",
        "state": "MA",
        "country": "USA",
        "zip": {
          "@location": "AP",
          "#text": "02139"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "2",
    "address_name": [
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "1",
          "full_address": "Univ Kentucky, Lexington, KY 40506 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Univ Kentucky",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "University of Kentucky"
              }
            ]
          },
          "city": "Lexington",
          "state": "KY",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "40506"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "2",
          "full_address": "Univ Bonn, ZEI, D-5300 Bonn, Germany",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Univ Bonn",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "University of Bonn"
              }
            ]
          },
          "suborganizations": {
            "@count": "1",
            "suborganization": "ZEI"
          },
          "city": "Bonn",
          "country": "Germany",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "BC",
            "#text": "D-5300"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "1",
    "address_name": {
      "address_spec": {
        "@addr_no": "1",
        "full_address": "Harvard Univ, Cambridge, MA 02138 USA",
        "organizations": {
          "@count": "2",
          "organization": [
            "Harvard Univ",
            {
              "@pref": "Y",
              "#text": "Harvard University"
            }
          ]
        },
        "city": "Cambridge",
        "state": "MA",
        "country": "USA",
        "zip": {
          "@location": "AP",
          "#text": "02138"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "3",
    "address_name": [
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "1",
          "full_address": "Columbia Univ, New York, NY 10027 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Columbia Univ",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "Columbia University"
              }
            ]
          },
          "city": "New York",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "10027"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "2",
          "full_address": "NYU, New York, NY USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "NYU",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "New York University"
              }
            ]
          },
          "city": "New York",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "USA"
        }
      },
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "3",
          "full_address": "Univ Pompeu Fabra, Barcelona, Spain",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Univ Pompeu Fabra",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "Pompeu Fabra University"
              }
            ]
          },
          "city": "Barcelona",
          "country": "Spain"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "2",
    "address_name": [
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "1",
          "full_address": "Univ Chicago, Chicago, IL 60637 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Univ Chicago",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "University of Chicago"
              }
            ]
          },
          "city": "Chicago",
          "state": "IL",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "60637"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "2",
          "full_address": "Amer Bar Fdn, Chicago, IL 60611 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "1",
            "organization": "Amer Bar Fdn"
          },
          "city": "Chicago",
          "state": "IL",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "60611"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "2",
    "address_name": [
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "1",
          "full_address": "Ohio State Univ, Columbus, OH 43210 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Ohio State Univ",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "Ohio State University"
              }
            ]
          },
          "city": "Columbus",
          "state": "OH",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "43210"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "2",
          "full_address": "Harvard Univ, Cambridge, MA 02138 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Harvard Univ",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "Harvard University"
              }
            ]
          },
          "city": "Cambridge",
          "state": "MA",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "02138"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "1",
    "address_name": {
      "address_spec": {
        "@addr_no": "1",
        "full_address": "Univ Chicago, Chicago, IL 60637 USA",
        "organizations": {
          "@count": "2",
          "organization": [
            "Univ Chicago",
            {
              "@pref": "Y",
              "#text": "University of Chicago"
            }
          ]
        },
        "city": "Chicago",
        "state": "IL",
        "country": "USA",
        "zip": {
          "@location": "AP",
          "#text": "60637"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "2",
    "address_name": [
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "1",
          "full_address": "Wissensch Zentrum Berlin Sozialforsch, D-1000 Berlin, Germany",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "1",
            "organization": "Wissensch Zentrum Berlin Sozialforsch"
          },
          "city": "Berlin",
          "country": "Germany",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "BC",
            "#text": "D-1000"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "2",
          "full_address": "Harvard Univ, Dept Govt, Cambridge, MA 02138 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Harvard Univ",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "Harvard University"
              }
            ]
          },
          "suborganizations": {
            "@count": "1",
            "suborganization": "Dept Govt"
          },
          "city": "Cambridge",
          "state": "MA",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "02138"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "addresses": {
    "@count": "2",
    "address_name": [
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "1",
          "full_address": "NYU, CV Starr Ctr Appl Econ, New York, NY 10003 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "NYU",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "New York University"
              }
            ]
          },
          "suborganizations": {
            "@count": "1",
            "suborganization": "CV Starr Ctr Appl Econ"
          },
          "city": "New York",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "10003"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "address_spec": {
          "@addr_no": "2",
          "full_address": "Princeton Univ, Princeton, NJ 08544 USA",
          "organizations": {
            "@count": "2",
            "organization": [
              "Princeton Univ",
              {
                "@pref": "Y",
                "#text": "Princeton University"
              }
            ]
          },
          "city": "Princeton",
          "state": "NJ",
          "country": "USA",
          "zip": {
            "@location": "AP",
            "#text": "08544"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "category_info": {
    "headings": {
      "@count": "1",
      "heading": "Social Sciences"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "@count": "3",
      "subject": [
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "extended",
          "#text": "Business &amp; Economics"
        },
        {
          "@ascatype": "traditional",
          "#text": "ECONOMICS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I was hoping to extract is a country for each of the records (some records have more than one country, which seems to be causing the problem). So my naive approach was to say:

```
.static_data."fullrecord_metadata".addresses.address_name.country
```

This however gives me several errors (null has no keys, and cannot index array with string). Checking using the keys command:

```
.static_data."fullrecord_metadata".addresses.address_name | keys
```

I can see that it's seems there's a problem with the way the data is structured...

So, could you suggest if I can actually extract the list of countries for each entry using jq? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each input top-level JSON entity, the following filter will recursively examine all the objects to see if they have a "country" key, and it will then report the distinct "country" values for that top-level entity:

```
jq -c '[.. | if type == "object" and has("country") 
             then .country
             else empty end] | unique' 
["Israel"]
["USA"]
["Germany","USA"]
["USA"]
["Spain","USA"]
["USA"]
["USA"]
["USA"]
["Germany","USA"]
["USA"]
```

Here's a filter that will produce the same results in your example, though it is not exactly equivalent:

```
[.. | .country? // empty] | unique
```

[Exercise for the interested reader: what is the difference? :-) ]

Comment: Thank you VERY much! :) This is way too advanced for me to figure out on my own.

Comment: `.country? // empty` means that `.country` should be used if it exists and is not null, otherwise it will be substituted with empty. `unique` removes duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses a function to handle the variation in `.address_name`

```
 def address_specs:
    if type == "array" then .[].address_spec else .address_spec end
 ;

 .addresses | .address_name | [address_specs | .country] | unique
```